# What should I do with two slightly different questions with very similar answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, flags

I came upon two slightly different questions, with answers that were nearly identical:

[Communicating and persisting data between apps with App Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015506/communicating-and-persisting-data-between-apps-with-app-groups)

[Save and Load Data on Today Extensions (iOS 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064722/save-and-load-data-on-today-extensions-ios-8)

The first question was slightly more specific (OP had already figured out they needed to use app groups), and the second question gave a general problem, and the answer to that problem was using technology described in the first question.

The second question has two very similar similar answers, both are nearly identical to [an answer on the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24063144/2446155). One answer even linked to that answer on the first question.

I wanted to flag the second question as a duplicate of the first. The first question had a variety of answers (two solutions to the problem), so I thought it was the better question.

So I changed the title of the first question slightly, so that it could better apply to the second question, and any others like it. I also modified my answer to the first question, adding a piece of information that was present in an answer to the second question.

Then I flagged it, and that flag is still somewhere in some review queue somewhere.

**Did I do the right thing?** Should I just have left it as two questions?

Also, more generally, **if there are two similar questions with nearly identical answers, should they be modified and marked as duplicates?**

Comment: mark them as duplicate.